# How can I recognize a dot followed by a space and output dot?

Tags: macros, conditionals, plain-tex

In the following code I cannot figure out what to use for \SPACE and \DOT such that \peektoken is compared to a space( ) and a dot(.) is produced as output along with the result of the test T(rue) or F(alse).

```
\catcode`\.=\active
\def\dotnext{\ifx\peektoken\SPACE\DOT T\else \DOT F\fi}
\def.{\futurelet\peektoken\dotnext}
Lorem. Ipsum.  is. simply.  dummy text.
\bye
```

Comment: Making the period active is not something I'd do.

Comment: If you are doing this to adjust end-of-sentence space then tex has built in mechanisms for doing that. making `.` active will break almost all use of numbers, use of . as a null delimiter and many other things.

Comment: I'm hoping to build this into something that can recognize end-of-sentence in a controlled setting. End-of-sentence could be specified as occurring when a dot is followed by two spaces for example. Unfortunately i cannot even make it work for one space.

Comment: Is there any news here? Please edit your question.

Comment: @hkBst You won't be able to detect two spaces unless you change the catcode of the space.  In LaTeX, `. X` and `.      X` are interpreted the same... a dot followed by ONE space, followed by an `X`.

Answer (score 1):

You want `\SPACE` to be `\let` to a space token for the `\ifx` test, and `\DOT` to be `\let` to a catcode12 . or `\def` to expand to a catcode 12 . (I do the latter here)

[image]

```
\def\DOT{.}
\catcode`\.=\active
\lowercase{\let\SPACE= } %

\def\dotnext{\ifx\peektoken\SPACE\DOT T\else \DOT F\fi}
\def.{\futurelet\peektoken\dotnext}
Lorem. Ipsum.  is. simply.  dummy text.

a.b.c.

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

I address a comment made by the OP: *"I'm hoping to build this into something that can recognize end-of-sentence in a controlled setting. End-of-sentence could be specified as occurring when a dot is followed by two spaces for example."*

Here I use a token cycle as the OP's "controlled setting" to momentarily change the catcode of the space if a dot is located, so that what follows can be checked for the presence of two or more spaces to indicate an `(END-OF-SENTENCE)`.  A single space or a non-space character does not trigger the criterion.

Multiple spaces in the absence of a leading dot are treated in the expected TeX way...as a single space token.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\bgroup
\catcode32=12 %
\global\def\charsp{ }%
\egroup
\Characterdirective{%
  \addcytoks{#1}%
  \ifx.#1%
    \catcode32=12 %
    \tcpop\Q%
    \ifx\charsp\Q
      \tcpop\QQ\ifx\charsp\QQ\addcytoks{(END-OF-SENTENCE)}%
          \catcode32=10 \tcpop\QQQ\tcpush\QQQ%
        \else
        \addcytoks[1]{ \QQ}\fi%
    \else\addcytoks[1]{\Q}\fi
    \catcode32=10 %
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\tokencyclexpress
Four spaces follow dot.    %
Three spaces follow dot.   %
Two spaces follow dot.  %
One space follows dot. %
No spaces follow dot.%
End
\endtokencyclexpress
\end{document}
```

[image]